# How to read and write email in terminal? Does gmail require a special software?

Tags: email, postfix, gmail, mutt

I wonder if anybody still does something like this. What are current options today?

I'm using Ubuntu12, and trying to install mutt. What should I apt-get-install, mutt of mutt-patched?

While I'm installing mutt, a "Postfix Configuration" window appears. Why do I need postfix, and which of those options should I choose?

- No configuration
- Internet Site
- Internet with smarthost
- Satellite system
- Local only

Does gmail counts as Internet Site? What are MSTP, smarthost, fetchmail?

Is this link not outdated yet? It doesn't tell anything about installing postfix, though. http://lifehacker.com/5574557/how-to-use-the-fast-and-powerful-mutt-email-client-with-gmail

Also, I need an email client with a simple enough source code, which even I will understand.

Does gmail have any quirks that may make it incompatible with a usual clients? For example, how reply quoting is made in gmail and usual emails? Which formatting is used for that, flattext and ">" at the beginning of every line?

How to use mail lists?

Comment: Python has a good email library. So if you want to understand the code, it's probably the best to write it yourself! There must be a lot of examples on the web about this...

Comment: It is better if you post one question per question; then, it can be answered in isolation, and you can mark it as accepted when you have received an answer which satisfies you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `mutt` pulls in a Message Transport Agent, because `mutt` by itself can only (on today's internet) talk to your local MTA.  If you prefer a different MTA than Postfix, you can choose Exim or Sendmail (for example) instead, but I recommend you stay with Postfix.

For your scenario, it sounds like you would want to define Gmail as your smarthost (where Postfix sends all outgoing mail for further delivery).  Another popular model is to use your ISP's smarthost.

SMTP (not MSTP) is the protocol which `mutt` uses to submit an email message to Postfix, and which Postfix uses to talk to other mail servers.

`fetchmail` is a popular tool for pulling down email from a remote account (such as Gmail) to a local set of mail folders.  It used to be popular for people who had intermittent Internet access through a metered connection; it still makes sense if for some reason you want your email to be stored in local files (perhaps because you want to process them programmatically, and can't run stuff over IMAP, or locally on a remote mail server).

Answer (score 1):

If you interested in going 'old school' perhaps (and don't want to use IMAP)  have a look at this Ubuntu Wiki guide:

[Mutt And Gmail](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MuttAndGmail)

and this will give you some copy and paste instructions that only require minor editing to get you sending and receiving from Gmail.